# URL rewrite issue not loading .css

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm porting *an old site* to a *new template* and am having problems with the Windows 2008 rewrite module. The link I'm trying to rewrite looks like this:

`http://ltweb2008.serveronline.net/product.php?pID=75`

and brings up the page just fine. Then I apply the new URL and it loads the proper content, but doesn't load the *template's style.css* file anymore.

`http://ltweb2008.serveronline.net/product/75/any-text-here`

The problem seems to be that the company who made the template (canvas) put the main `.css` file in the root directory, but loaded all the rest in /css. Now I can't get the main `.css` file to load using the **rewrite** and when I move it down to /css it only displays a *blank page*, though when I check out the page source it's all there.

With this the page shows but is not using style.css (with rewrite):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />`

With any of these the page is completely blank (with rewrite):

1. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" />` OR
2. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" />` OR
3. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ltweb2008.serveronline.net/style.css" type="text/css" />`

*I'm using this for the Pattern:*

`^product/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$`

*And the Rewrite URL:*

`/product.php?pID={R:1}`

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> one solution is that use absolute path (ex /css, or /js rather than just css/, /js but this is not looks a reliable solution since we've to change it on all files,

This is because your relative URIs have their base changed. Originally, the base is `/` when the page is `/product.php?id=75`, and the browser properly fills in relative links with the `/` base. But when the browser goes to a page like `/product/75/any-text-here` the base suddenly becomes `/product/` and it tries to append that in front of all relative URLs and thus none of them load.

You can either make your links absolute, or change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need one thing, maybe both, I didn't test, but this solved it for me:

1.) ADD THIS in page_load :

`Page.Header.DataBind()` ' Needed because we have `<%# %>` codeblocks in the HEADER (seems header only causing this) WITH the `AjaxControlToolkit` running on the page. That's what broke it until we put in this and put in the pound instead of = sign in the html.

2.) Add this in ASPX:

`<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/dir1/dir2whateverdir/MasterPage.master"  %>`